# Double pointer null check in c

Tags: c, pointers, double-pointer

How to check if a double pointer is `NULL` in the C language ?

I pass a double pointer how parameter of a function.

I need to check twice, like so ???

```
typedef struct no_t no_t;

struct no_t
{
    no_t *prev;
    no_t *next;
    void *obj;
};

int32_t dynll_free_node_and_object(no_t **node)
{
    if (node == NULL)
        return -1;
    
    if (*node == NULL)
        return -2; 

    free((*node)->obj);
    (*node)->obj = NULL;
    
    (*node)->prev = NULL;
    (*node)->next = NULL;

    free(*node);  
    *node = NULL;
    
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You can do it like that if you want, nothing inherently wrong with that. Note that `(*node)->obj = NULL;` `(*node)->prev = NULL;` `(*node)->next = NULL;` serve no purpose because the next line makes `*node` an invalid pointer so you can never misuse those three pointers.

Comment: You dereference both `node` and `*node`, so if your paranoia of potential null is well suited, you have little choice but to check both. Also, you have two distinct return values (-1 when `node` is null, and -2 when `*node` is null), that is even more fuel for having to check  both (assuming those are genuinely acted upon with similar distinct by the caller and not just there for kicks).

Answer (score 3):

Checking both `node` and `*node` is fine, but the function could be documented as only accepting a non null address and passing the address of a null pointer might not be an error.  For example `free(NULL)` is perfectly fine.

Also note that setting the fields to `NULL` is optional as you free the structure memory anyway and reset `*node` to `NULL` so the calling code would have to dereference a copy of the original pointer to attempt to read the freed structure and this would have undefined behavior anyway.

Here is a simplified version:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct no_t {
    no_t *prev;
    no_t *next;
    void *obj;
} no_t;

void dynll_free_node_and_object(no_t **node) {
    assert(node);
    
    if (*node) {
        free((*node)->obj);
        free(*node);
        *node = NULL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if( node == NULL )
    return -1;
    
if( *node == NULL )
    return -2;
```

That is one way to do it. Code risks invoking undefined behaviour if only `*node` was checked (`node` could potentially be `NULL`), or if it was checked first (for the aforementioned reason).

If the different return values only serves noise, consider returning -1 if either is `NULL`:

```
if (!node || !(*node)) {
    return -1;
}
```

You may instead want to `abort()` the program:

```
/* assert() would be disabled in release build. */
abort ();
```

Or perhaps simulate `free(NULL)` by allowing a `NULL` pointer. It will be a NOP.

Note that setting these pointers to `NULL` like so:

```
(*node)->obj = NULL;
(*node)->prev = NULL;
(*node)->next = NULL;
```

is pointless because the subsequent assignment of `NULL` to `*node` invalidates it. `*node` no longer points to its original location, so the freed memory can not be accessed through it. (It's not your problem if the caller saved a copy of the original pointer and tried to access memory after it was freed). — @n.m.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the fact that `||` will short-circuit its right-hand side if it can. I.e if the left hand-size evaluates to `1` (or any non-zero value), it will not run the expression on its right-hand side.

```
if(node == NULL || *node == NULL)
  return -1;
```

That makes you use the same return code on failure though.

Comment: The affirmative case is `if (node && *node)`

Comment: && need to satisfy both evaluations, and is wrong, the correct is || or.